# Verifying a purchase on android using Firebase cloud function and Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been working on a function to verify purchase on android device.
From here and there, I got this code which uses Firebase realtime database, which I'm not trying to use:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const publisher = google.androidpublisher('v2');
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: 'Service Account Email',
    key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n**********************************************************************************==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
});
admin.initializeApp();

exports.validatePurchases = functions.database
    .ref('/purchases/{uId}/{orderId}')
    .onCreate((event, context) => {
        const purchase = event.val();
        if (purchase.is_processed === true) {
            console.log('Purchase already processed!, exiting');
            return null;
        }
        const orderId = context.params.orderId;
        const dbRoot = event.ref.root;
        const package_name = purchase.package_name;
        const sku = purchase.sku;
        const my_token = purchase.token;

        authClient.authorize((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            publisher.purchases.products.get({
                auth: authClient,
                packageName: package_name,
                productId: sku,
                token: my_token
            }, (err, response) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                // Result Status must be equals to 200 so that the purchase is valid
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return event.ref.child('is_validated').set(true);
                } else {
                    return event.ref.child('is_validated').set(false);
                }
            });
        });
        return null;
    });
```

How to convert his to Firebase firestore's in conjuction with functions and how to call it from android device?

Comment: Dude, you just copy pasted my answer , really!! "I've been working on a function...", really 

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible approaches :

**1/ From your app, call a Cloud Function that interacts with Firestore**

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) you can call a Cloud Function from your app:

> The Cloud Functions for Firebase client SDKs let you call functions
>   directly from a Firebase app. To call a function from your app in this
>   way, write and deploy an HTTPS Callable function in Cloud Functions,
>   and then add client logic to call the function from your app.

In this HTTPS Callable Function you can interact with the Firestore database the way you wish (read/write/modify/delete) and return some data to your app.

The [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#writing_data) for Firestore and Cloud Functions shows how to write and read to/from Firestore in a Cloud Function. There is also one of the official samples that demonstrate how to interact with Firestore from an HTTP Cloud Function, [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/952fe5d08c0a416f78def93fa337ca2bd73aedcf/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js) (Not exactly a HTTPS Callable function but very similar).

You would call HTTPS Callable Function as follows (excerpt of the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) referenced above):

```
addMessage(inputMessage)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Exception e = task.getException();
                    if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                        FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                        FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                        Object details = ffe.getDetails();
                    }

                    // ...
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

**2/ Trigger a Cloud Function based on some events in Firestore and listen for the changes this Cloud Function executes**

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) for Firestore and Cloud Functions:

> You can deploy Node.js code to handle **events triggered by changes in
>   your Cloud Firestore database**....
>
> Firestore supports create, update,
>   delete, and write events.

You would then use listeners in your Android app to detect changes in Firestore, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

In your case, based on the code you included in your question you would write a value in an order document, which would trigger the call to `authClient.authorize()` (similarly to the Real Time database code in your question) and, on success, update/create another document to which you are listening in you app.

So with this approach you are not directly calling the Function

Comment: I'm a newbie, can you provide the cloud function that  is triggered(updating firestore) to verify purchase?

Comment: I would suggest you try to write some code and in case you encounter specific problems you ask for help. Without any doubt, the community will be happy to help you correcting **your** code.